# Extjs LoadPage: How to reduce the amount of background get uri requests

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to load/refresh the page once when the user clicks sort. Currently the page gets the data couple of times in the back background , but visually the data is being  displayed perfectly correct, no issue with teh display of the data.

My consern is performance tuning, I am trying to reduce background  get requests for the data once .(When I use firbug console and go to >net tab >ALL , I notice couple of Get url requests when i clock sort).. i would prefer to be  be once or twice)

I was thinking of adding a counter to cut off when the counter reaches one or two.to teh code below.

What would be the best approach when the users clicks sorts..

```
  this.view.panel.store.addListener("load", dataLoadedCallback);  

    var currentPage = this.view.panel.store.getPageFromRecordIndex(visibleStart);

container.view.panel.store.loadPage(currentPage);  


 // Call Back function for addListener
    function dataLoadedCallback(dataStore, records, success){

 //I have some code hereto handle the callback

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't happen. The data for the store should be loaded once for initial display and each time you sort it (if you are remote sorting it of course). I wonder if you have extra listeners setup on sort events that force more loads?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the @DmitryB answer - if your first line of code where you add listener is called several times - you will have several `load` handlers and your function will be executed more then one time.

If you need to make sure handler is called just once - check `options` parameter in addListener and pass `{ single: true }`

Comment: Is this the right way to go about adding the options? this.view.panel.store.addListener("load", dataLoadedCallback){ single: true };

Comment: no. it should be something like ('load', function() {}, scope /* this? */, { single: true } - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-addListener